# Parsing LaTex author tag to extract author names

Tags: python, latex, nltk, author, named-entity-recognition

**1. Author tag:**

```
\author{{\small Tanya Araujo$^{a,b}$ and Elsa Fontainha$^{a}$} \and {\small $^{a}$ISEG
(Lisbon School of Economics \& Management) Universidade de Lisboa, } \and
{\small Rua do Quelhas, 6 1200-781 Lisboa Portugal} \and {\small $^{b}$Research
Unit on Complexity and Economics (UECE)} \and {\small Rua Miguel Lupi, 20
1249-078 Lisboa Portugal}}

\author{{\bf R. Vilela Mendes} \and {\small Grupo de Fisica Matematica, Av.
Gama Pinto 2,} \and {\small \ 1699 Lisboa Codex, Portugal
(vilela@cii.fc.ul.pt)} \and {\bf Tanya Araujo and Francisco Lou\cc\a%
} \and {\small Departamento de Economia, ISEG,} \and {\small R. Miguel Lupi
20, 1200 Lisboa, Portugal} \and {\small (tanya@iseg.utl.pt,
flouc@iseg.utl.pt)}}
```

**2. Removed special characters, other tags, emails and numbers:**

Tanya Araujo and Elsa Fontainha   ISEG
Lisbon School of Economics & Management Universidade de Lisboa, Rua do Quelhas,  - Lisboa Portugal   Research
Unit on Complexity and Economics UECE   Rua Miguel Lupi, 
- Lisboa Portugal

R. Vilela Mendes   Grupo de Fisica Matematica, Av.
Gama Pinto ,     Lisboa Codex, Portugal
   Tanya Araujo and Francisco Lou
   Departamento de Economia, ISEG,   R. Miguel Lupi
,  Lisboa, Portugal   ,

**3. Desired Output:**
To extract only the names and remove university names or any location names. Tried to use NER from NLTK but it recognizes Universidade and Lisboa as PERSON, etc.

```
(PERSON Tanya/NNP)
  (PERSON Araujo/NNP)
  and/CC
  (PERSON Elsa/NNP Fontainha/NNP)
  ISEG/NNP
  (/(
  (ORGANIZATION Lisbon/NNP School/NNP)
  of/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Economics/NNP)
  &/CC
  Management/NNP
  )/)
  (PERSON Universidade/NNP)
  de/FW
  (PERSON Lisboa/NNP)
  ,/,
  (PERSON Rua/NNP)
  do/VBP
  (PERSON Quelhas/NNP)
  ,/,
  -/:
  (PERSON Lisboa/NNP Portugal/NNP Research/NNP Unit/NNP)
  on/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Complexity/NNP)
  and/CC
  (GPE Economics/NNP)
  (/(
  (ORGANIZATION UECE/NNP)
  )/)
  (PERSON Rua/NNP Miguel/NNP Lupi/NNP)
  ,/,
  -/:
  (PERSON Lisboa/NNP Portugal/NNP Alessandro/NNP Spelta/NNP)
  corresponding/VBG
  author/NN
  :/:
  and/CC
  (PERSON Tanya/NNP Araujo/NNP))
```

Is it possible to resolve this issue using NER from NLTK or should we try any other libraries like spaCy?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup, which would extract the author elements, like this.

```
>>> from TexSoup import TexSoup
>>> soup = TexSoup(open('tri7.txt').read())
>>> for i in soup.find_all('author'):
...     i
...     
\author{{\small Tanya Araujo$^{a,b}$ and Elsa Fontainha$^{a}$} \and {\small $^{a}$ISEG
(Lisbon School of Economics \& Management) Universidade de Lisboa, } \and
{\small Rua do Quelhas, 6 1200-781 Lisboa Portugal} \and {\small $^{b}$Research
Unit on Complexity and Economics (UECE)} \and {\small Rua Miguel Lupi, 20
1249-078 Lisboa Portugal}}
```

Then you could extract the strings exemplified by

```
{{\small Tanya Araujo$^{a,b}$ and Elsa Fontainha$^{a}$}
```

in this case, in any of a number of ways.
Finally, you could drop items such as `\small` and `$(a,b)$` using regex, if you can't make TexSoup do this for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Bill. This is restricted to this particular case but what if there are many other formats which are not similar to this. I am sorry for the question being specific to this case alone.

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by 'other formats'?

Comment: I mean the author tags in different format. Please check another author tag I updated in the description.

Comment: I see. If the author entries are irregular like that it will be likely be considerably more challenging. My inclination would be to try to identify patterns in them. You might be able to reduce the amount of coding needed -- but I'd expect to do quite a bit of analysis work.